# gfortran cannot find FFTW3 library on Ubuntu 12.04 though it works on Linux Mint 17.3

Tags: ubuntu, fortran, fftw

I am using FFTW3 and gfortran on Ubuntu 12.04 and Linux Mint 17.3.
Although I wrote the same codes for both OS, it does not work only in Ubuntu.
For both, I installed as follows:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gfortran libfftw3-dev
```

Then, I can find 
`/usr/include/fftw3.f03`
in both.
Moreover, I can find `/usr/lib/libfftw3.a` (and `*.so`) in Ubuntu and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.a` (and `*.so`) in Linux Mint.

Next, I wrote the following fortran code:

```
program test
use,intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
implicit none
(statements)
include 'fftw3.f03"
...
plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, signal, spectrum, -1, fftw_estimate)
call fftw_execute_dft(plan, signal, spectrum)
...
```

By compiling it via

`$ gfortran test.f03 -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib -lfftw3 -lm`

I obtain an executable file in Linux Mint.
However, Ubuntu says

```
/tmp/(random charcters).o: In function `Main__':
test.f03:(.text+0x9ce): undefined reference to `fftw_plan_dft_1d'
test.f03:(.text+0x9ef): undefined reference to `fftw_execute_dft'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Versions of gfortran and FFTW3:
For Ubuntu 12.04,

- gfortran 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
- libfftw3-dev 3.3-1ubuntu1

For Linux Mint 17.3,

- gfortran 4.8.2-1ubuntu6
- libfftw3-dev 3.3-7ubuntu3

Should I use different compile options in Ubuntu? 
Or did I wrongly specify the library directry?
Please let me know something related to.
Thanks.